# Unable to use email shortcut option in Office 365 Excel and Winword apps

Tags: office365, excel-2016, word-2016

Unable to attach the documents and send emails using email shortcut button which is available in Excel and Winword apps

Sometimes it works but most of the times it's giving the following error message

"General mail failure. Quit Microsoft Excel, restart the mail system, and try again."

Also, the following error message pops up when Outlook gets open the first time.

"Sorry, we're having trouble starting Outlook. Only one version of Outlook can run at a time. Check to see if another version of Outlook is running, or try restarting your computer."

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.  I approached my technical team and they suggested a wipe of my computer . . that seems a bit harsh!  I look forward to an answer and will share if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I only experienced this message when I clicked on the icon that I pinned in the taskbar, while Outlook was already running (ages ago).

**To fix my issue:**

- Unpin the shortcut from the Taskbar
- Restart Outlook
- Pin the new Outlook icon to the Taskbar

My infrastructure team have not had any other reports of this in the organisation, it does not seem like it's related to an Office or Windows update, so I have no causes to report, however my fix above solved this problem for me.

Hope it does for you as well!